# ExtJs _dc parameter starts with "/" slash

Tags: javascript, extjs

The 'Disable Cache' feature in ExtJs is like this:

```
myurl/?_dc=1263286227619
```

However, when I have a link like this:

```
http://localhost/api/users?format=json&locale=en/&_dc=1263286227619
```

My `locale` parameter now has value of "en/" instead of "en". ExtJs puts an extra `/` in front of `&`.

I am using ExtJs 4.2. How do I go around this issue?

[image]

**UPDATE** --------------------------------------------------------

[image]

I check the library source code, my link seems okay until it comes to `buildUrl()` function, yellow highlight indicates where url got the extra slash. (blocked out the company project name)

Comment: I've just tried replicating this in JSFiddle; works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/jKASB/2/). Could you show the exact code you're using?

Comment: @kryger, I have updated the question, please see. it is part of a big project, the way I do it is like this. url is assigned to someModel.getProxy().url; then someModel.data.load('', callback...);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is too vague, but my best guess is:

You're using a REST proxy, which means it's attempting to append an id to the load so the url looks like:

`/foo/bar/user/1`

The problem is you've encoded the params as part of the url,

`url: '/foo/bar/?format=json&locale=en`

However, you should specify those parameters as part of the extraParams on the proxy:

```
{
    url: '/foo/bar',
    extraParams: {
        format: 'json',
        locale: 'en'
    }
}
```

However, as I said above, you haven't even provided any code, so this is just a guess.

Comment: Yes, I always picked a REST proxy, didn't know it actually makes a difference. You found the issue! Thank you :P